# Partial not receiving all variables from :locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have:

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = render :partial => 'item', :locals => { :item => item, :draggable => true }
```

And in the `item` partial I have:

```
%span{:id => "item_#{item.id}", :class => 'item'}
  = item.name
  - if defined?(draggable)
    = draggable_element "item_#{item.id}", :revert => true
```

This is not working, however, because `defined?(draggable)` returns `false`. The `draggable_element` is never rendered.

I know that `item` is passed through `:locals` because the rest of the partial renders. If I change the partial to read:

```
- if defined?(item)
  = draggable_element "item_#{item.id}", :revert => true
```

Then the `draggable_element` is rendered.

Any *idea* why `:draggable` is not getting passed to the partial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `local_assigns[:draggable]` instead of `defined?(draggable)`.

From the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html) "Testing using `defined? var` will not work. This is an implementation restriction."

Comment: defined?(var) actually worked for me in all other instances, but obviously is not the way to go! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in the past by throwing this into the top of the partial.

```
 <% draggable ||= nil %>
```

That allows me to do

```
 <% if draggable %>
```

So long as I don't try to make the distinction between draggable being nil and never being passed.